# How can I use nodes to make a Genshin-like grass material?

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, instances, geometry-nodes

I have tried to make grass just like in Genshin, but it is still not like how I want it in EEVEE.

- Game Screenshot

[image: Game screenshot]

- My Grass

[image: My grass]

Comment: Your grass is a little bit washed out, which actually annoys me about the grass in reality. Maybe you want to resign from *Filmic* view transform? Or decrease the strength of light.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the only thing you're missing is some color variation for each blade of grass.

If each blade of grass is an individual object, you can create variation with *Object Info -> Random* plugged into a *Hue/Saturation* node.

[image]

If you have a clump of grass where multiple blades comprise the same object but each blade is separate, you need to mix in *Geometry -> Random Per Island*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest slightly bigger grass blades, with a gradient image for the color.

I think there's not as many individual blades in the game VS yours.

Lastly, and I might be wrong there, but I think that the game's blade's bottom are fading to transparent and are placed on a same color green surface.

Hope these bullet points help you!